# Error in FWHM of photo peak

Tags: computational-physics, spectroscopy, statistics, software

I have spectra for different sources I need to find the FWHM of to determine energy resolution of a scintillation detector.
I have taken spectra and then fitted a gaussian to the photopeak:
[image: Na22 Spectrum]

[image]
The scipy curvefit:

```
mean = np.mean(y)
sigma = np.std(y)
    def gauss(x,a,x0,sigma):
    return a*exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))

popt,pcov = curve_fit(gauss,x,y,p0=[50,mean,sigma],maxfev=2000)
#plt.plot(x, gauss(y, *popt), label='fit')
print(popt)

fwhm = 2.3548*popt[2]
print(fwhm)
```

gives a standard error in the parameters. I get popt=[ 41.24088326 , 1.27667677 , 0.05080018] and:

```
perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
```

gives perr=[ 1.52600256, 0.00221915, 0.00270209]. These are one standard error on matching element parameters in popt. So I took the error in the FWHM as

```
(perr[2]/popt[2])*fwhm
```

Is this wrong? I feel it is but not sure how else I can get an error on the FWHM of the peak.

Comment: I think you need to show the formula (in Maxthjax) that you are using, and not just code. (and I am *The Pystro*)...and fit a background, which looks like it might be sloped...more parameters.

Comment: It's perr[2]*2..3548 in so far as your model and fitting method will give.

Comment: Why do you fit a Gaussian? As far as I remember, spectral peaks are often Lorenzian, due to their "resonance nature". To see this, we take an harmonic oscillator and evaluate it's spectrum.

Comment: @RobJeffries That is what I have done, my error cancels to that formula. I was just checking because the error seems very small.
 I'd never heard of Lorenzian curve, I just assumed I can fit a gaussian because I'm observing decay processes with counts and I'm only essentially interested in the FWHM of the data here